# how to replace a character in an array java?

Tags: java

I'm doing a function in which I need to get user input and replace all of the vowels in the array with what the user put. This is my array: I honestly dont know what im doing .

```
char [] letters = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'}
```

I'm thinking of doing a nested `if` inside the `for loop` but like I said I don't know if I'm headed in the right direction .

```
/********************************************************************************
  This function will prompt the user to replace all vowels in the array
********************************************************************************/
public static void replace( char [] letters ){      
    for(int i =0; i < letters.length; i++){
       if(i >= 'A')
        if(i <='Z')
         System.out.println(letters[i]);
        else
          break;        
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop doesn't look like it will do much other than print out all the upper case letters. You need some code to display a prompt and obtain user input. You also need a way to test whether a character is a vowel. One way of doing the latter is:

```
if ("AEIOU".indexOf(letter) >= 0) {
    // letter is a vowel
}
```

If you also need to handle lower case letters, you can use either `"AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(letter)` or `"AEIOU".indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(letter))`. This hides the nested loop inside a standard API function call, which makes your code more readable and easier to debug. (You can safely assume that `indexOf` is written correctly.)

For user interaction, you should look at wrapping `System.in` with a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Alternatively (and perhaps better), use a [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) for managing all user I/O. Take a look at [this tutoral](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html), see if you can figure it out on your own and if you get stuck, post another question.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to replace a, e, and i with another character that the user has typed in.

1. You're comparing your index 'i' to characters, you will probably want to change that to

> ```
> if(letters[i] >= 'A') 
> if(letters[i] <= 'Z') 
> System.out.println(letters[i]); 
> else 
> break;
> ```

Another thing, if you want to test to see if it is a vowel, you could OR all the comparisons together like this:

> ```
> if(letters[i] == 'A' ||
>    letters[i] == 'E' ||
>    letters[i] == 'I' ||
>    letters[i] == 'O' ||
>    letters[i] == 'U')
> letters[i] = users_input
> ```

Comment: yes if the user inputs an L for example i need it to print {'L', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'L', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'L', 'J'}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
public static void replace( char [] letters )
{      

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
    {

        if ("AEIOU".indexOf(letters[i]) >= 0)
        {
              System.out.println("\nVowel Found, What should it be replaced with?");
              String line = s.read();
              letter[i] = line.charAt(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume user input is `b`, you can achieve this:

```
public static char [] replace(char [] src) {
    String s = new String(src);
    s = s.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", "b");

    return s.toCharArray();
}
```